# vTestStudio: Type library generation for canoe configuration internal system gerneration failed

Tags: capl, canoe

When I am importing canoe configuration variable in vTestStudio i am getting "type library generation for canoe configuration internal system gerneration failed". Due to this many of the canoe variable i dont find in vteststudio. Could anyone help me on how to resolve it

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the exact error message, including all messages before and after it.
Apart from that, it might be better to contact Vector support instead of asking here.

Comment: Thank You for responding. I have posted the exact thing what I am getting when trying to import. I was just checking if anyone faced the same. Anyhow I will check the same with vector.